# Can't set headers after they are sent. NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

Following is my code where i first authenticate if the users are present in the group and if present push the accounts into the array and save. This is done via a POST request on /addaccount.

```
groupRouter.post('/addaccount', Verify.verifyOrdinaryUser, function(req, res, next) {
Groups.findById(req.body.group, function(err,group) {
    if (err) next(err);
    var checkUser = function(user) {
        for(var i=0; i<group.users.length; i++)
        {
            if(group.users[i]==user)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    if(checkUser(req.decoded._doc._id)){
        User.find({mobile:{$in:req.body.split}}, function(err, users) {
            if(err) next(err); var flag = true;
            if(users.length == req.body.split.length ) {
                for(var i=0; i<users.length; i++) {
                    if(!checkUser(''+users[i]._id)) {
                        flag = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(flag) {
                    var myObject = {};
                    myObject.amount = req.body.amount;
                    myObject.by = req.decoded._doc._id;
                    myObject.split = req.body.split;
                    group.accounts.push(myObject);
                    group.save(function (err, groups) {
                        if(err) next(err);
                        console.log('Added entries');
                        res.json(groups);
                    })
                }
                else
                    res.end('All users not in the group');
            }
            else
                res.end('Split users do not exist');
        })
    }
    else
        res.end('No Permission');
})
})
```

Now when I input an array of users and try to push an object and save via the
code below:

```
if(flag) {
                var myObject = {};
                myObject.amount = req.body.amount;
                myObject.by = req.decoded._doc._id;
                myObject.split = req.body.split;
                group.accounts.push(myObject);
                group.save(function (err, groups) {
                    if(err) next(err);
                    console.log('Added entries');
                    res.json(groups);
                })
            }
```

I get an error saying Error: Can't set headers after they are sent. as shown below.

```
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:357:11)
at ServerResponse.header (D:\Ionic\PocketBuddies\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:718:10)
at ServerResponse.send (D:\Ionic\PocketBuddies\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:163:12)
at done (D:\Ionic\PocketBuddies\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:957:10)
at Object.exports.renderFile (D:\Ionic\PocketBuddies\node_modules\jade\lib\index.js:374:12)
at View.exports.__express [as engine] (D:\Ionic\PocketBuddies\node_modules\jade\lib\index.js:417:11)
at View.render (D:\Ionic\PocketBuddies\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:126:8)
at tryRender (D:\Ionic\PocketBuddies\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:639:10)
at EventEmitter.render (D:\Ionic\PocketBuddies\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:591:3)
at ServerResponse.render (D:\Ionic\PocketBuddies\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:961:7)
at D:\Ionic\PocketBuddies\app.js:78:7
at Layer.handle_error (D:\Ionic\PocketBuddies\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:71:5)
at trim_prefix (D:\Ionic\PocketBuddies\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:310:13)
at D:\Ionic\PocketBuddies\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:7
at Function.process_params (D:\Ionic\PocketBuddies\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:330:12)
at IncomingMessage.next (D:\Ionic\PocketBuddies\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:271:10)
```

I searched for the issue and it says i cannot update the response after res.end(), but I dont see any res.end() being called here when i res.json is called.
Please help me find an issue here.
I am working on a project and this error is getting me crazy.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's happening in `D:\Ionic\PocketBuddies\app.js` on line 78? That's triggering the error. Also, you have to return from the current scope at each place you're calling `next(err)` (so `if (err) return next(err)`). My guess is that there's an error happening, your app is rendering an error page, but because you're not returning, the code _also_ hits `res.json()` or `res.end()` (triggering the error).

Comment: line 78 is where i am calling group.save() above.

Comment: also thanks for suggestion, will add return with next()

Comment: Well yes you were right, it was rendering an error page and then also hitting the res.json(), Thanks finally got the actual error !!

Comment: your two loops can be simplified: `var checkUser = userId => group.users.includes(userId);` and `var flag = users.every(user => checkUser(user._id));` And this can be simplified too: `group.accounts.push({
       amount: req.body.amount,
       by: req.decoded._doc._id,
       split: req.body.split
      })` just insert a few Line breaks (wich don't show up in comments)

Comment: Side-remark: sometimes [returning early](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/18473) can make your code cleaner.

Comment: @Thomas this does simplify the code but does it also make a difference in performance?

Comment: @Mikey where exactly are you pointing at? Where should i have returned earlier?

Comment: @RonakShah maybe, but no significant performance difference, only readability. Till you have actual performance issues you should only be concerned about readability, simplicity and how easy a piece of code is to read/scan/understand; simple code, understandable code => less logical errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As correctly pointed out by [robertklep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/893780/robertklep) the problem here was that the error was not returned and hence in the group.save() function after the error it rendered the error page as well as it hit the res.json() which caused the error.
It works fine if there are no errors.
The code needs to be updated as follows to return the error if it occurs and not move on to the res.json() part.

```
group.save(function (err, groups) {
                    if(err) return next(err);
                    console.log('Added entries');
                    res.json(groups);
                })
```

This did the trick for me by giving me the actual error which then had to be corrected post which things worked properly.